# How to Add or Create a Map Scale Bar to a Map created with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am seeking help with creating a map scale bar for use with a D3.js zoomable map.  I often create maps for my job using D3.js. I never placed a scale bar on the maps I built in the past but I recently gotten requests to include a scale bar on the maps.  I searched the web for some type of example to build off of, but I couldn't find anything.  I toyed around with d3.scale.linear() but I'm unable to create anything useful.

What I'm trying to create is a map scale bar that adjust it's numbers accordingly when zooming in and out with d3.behavior.zoom().  Any help with this issue (a working model or something to build off of) will greatly be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Mr. Reid I appreciate your detailed post.  This is what I was hoping to receive.  I will give it a try and report back my results. Thank you.

Comment: It worked!!!  I was able to create the scale bar and it placed in the correct numbers.  Now I will play around with the zoom issue you suggested.  Problem solved thanks to you.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Mr. Reid, the redraw option you suggested works great.  I placed your start scale script into a function and placed the function call in the new page of  the new view of the map.  I removed the scroll zoom to a click and load an updated map with a new map view.  I feel this click load new map view concept is tailored better for my user and offer them a better user experience; removing zoom scrolling and panning.  I hope that make sense.  Thanks again for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a D3.js plugin called d3-geo-scale-bar that should accomplish what you're looking for.

Here's the GitHub repo: https://github.com/HarryStevens/d3-geo-scale-bar

Here's a basic demo: https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/8c8d3a489aa1372e14b8084f94b32464

And here's a demo with pan and zoom: https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/64fc5f1a4489abe78433b7d19510f864

Here's an Observable notebook demo: https://observablehq.com/d/75249011244aafd6

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was trying to accomplish with the classic look, you have in your concept.  I appreciate you sharing this!

Comment: You're welcome. Please let me know if you have any issues with it so I can improve it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues you need to address in a web scale bar:

- Map distances will vary across a projection
- D3 projections project lat long data, which can't directly be used to measure physical distance
- Physical distance must be measured using great circle distance

I designed a scale for a map a while back that used the formula [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) for physical distance between to geographic coordinates. But what two points do you  use to measure distance? I used two points that when connected formed a line through the center of the map frame (horizontally and not to the edges for a landscape oriented map) the scale near the center of the map is likely most representative of the map scale as a whole.  To get the geographic location of a point using svg coordinates, use `projection.invert([x,y])` to get your longitude and latitude.

With the two points, you should then be able to calculate physical distance and svg coordinate distance, giving you the information needed for a scale. This might look like:

```
var scaleWidth = width / 4;
var p1 = projection.invert([width/2 - scaleWidth/2, height / 2]);
var p2 = projection.invert([width/2 + scaleWidth/2, height / 2]);
var geoDistance = getDistance(p1,p2);
```

Where `getDistance` is a function that returns the great circle distance between two geographic points, and the geographic distance this function returns is represented by `width/4` pixels on the map. Now, for the simplest scale, you can draw a rectangle `width/4 pixels` wide and label it as being the distance returned by `getDistance` long.

Note that if you choose the same two svg points every time as your reference points for the scale, the scale bar may show a un-round length. So, you'll need to modify the distance until you get a sufficiently round number, and then draw the scale bar in a corner (unless a scale bar 1.954 km wide is ok, this will be faster too).

To zoom, just redraw (and recalculate the distance between two central points, zoom factor will not help you in this) and/or transition the scale to represent the new physical distance between the reference points (recalculating them as needed to make a round number).

[Here's a bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/7e2096170ae87ce85ee0455fe959e376) of the scale in action, and an image of it below:

[image]

Comment: Mr. Reid, I tried to follow your suggestion on how to update the scalebar information when zooming a map. I toyed with both suggestions, redraw or transition the scalebar. I can't get either to work. Can you please update your block for the scalebar concept to show this zoom capability?

The static version works great but their are maps I included zooming and it would be great if the scale bar stays in place and updates itself when being zoomed.

Your help will greatly improve my maps. I really appreciate any help you have time to provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will take a look and try to demo an implementation,  but I have limited resources at the moment - on vacation and on the road today.

Comment: Thank you for finding time to replying back while on vacation.   Your original scale bar is a work of art and is much appreciated by my audience!  I really appreciate you taking time to help with this request. I look forward to seeing your implementation.

Comment: I will not be able to post a detailed response for a few weeks, but I have a bl.ock largely coded with an intermittant internet connection and by phone. I have applied an enter selection for the bar's initial creation, and then I apply an update transition to it. The merge allows the bar, if already drawn, to complete the same transition into a scale bar of the current map. This block changes the projection's scale, a scaling of the svg would be a little different. The text is removed and redrawn as text doesnt transition smoothly.  The zoom mechanism is just to illustrate the scale bar change

Comment: The blocks formatting is poor, the zoom mechanism flimsy, and the map is just redrawn completely each time. I will update it to be a better example and provide an answer to your new question in late oct. But here is the block: https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/raw/04822ce16381356b961a39d014037542  , it should show how the scale can be updated

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.  I will review your bl.ock you just posted.  I really, really appreciate you taking time out doing your vacation to help with this issue!  I look forward to seeing your updated bl.ock in late Oct.

Comment: Oh my YES, I just reviewed your bl.ock and yes this is what I was trying to accomplish.  The scale bar numbers updates when the map zooms! I love this.  Can wait to see the late Oct version!  Thank you so much!!!!