# How to update scalebar numbers when zooming the map

Tags: d3.js

I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222003/how-to-add-or-create-a-map-scale-bar-to-a-map-created-with-d3-js) sometime ago on how to create a scale bar for a map created using d3.js. I received an answer and a link to a bl.ocks (create a map scale bar with d3 - https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/7e2096170ae87ce85ee0455fe959e376) for an example. The scale bar concept was exactly what I hoped for....very happy. worked well!

I also included in my question can the scale bar update when being zoomed. The answer provided to try was this below:

"To zoom, just redraw (and recalculate the distance between two central points, zoom factor will not help you in this) and/or transition the scale to represent the new physical distance between the reference points (recalculating them as needed to make a round number)."

I tried to follow this path but I'm not able to create anything that works.

I would appreciate if anyone that can provide any help on making this concept possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Or turn this into a standalone question i.e. include all the necessary context in this question so we can all understand what you're on about.